# modernizr script sequence and IE9

Tags: jquery, modernizr

I'm loading up jquery and modernizr in the head of my document like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr-columntest.js"></script>
```

"columntest.js" has some custom modernizr code straight from their generator, with a little yepnope call pasted onto the end of it that conditionally loads a plugin:

```
Modernizr.load({
  test: Modernizr.csscolumns,
  nope: 'js/jquery.masonry.js'
});
```

But the plug-in isn't firing correctly in IE9. After a lot of headscratching, I noticed in IE9 dev tools that a script tag with the conditionally loaded script is dynamically being appended to whatever element I place the modernizr script in. If the modernizr script is in the head, the generated script tag appears in the head in IE Dev Tools. If I put it the modernizr call in the body, the generated script appears in the body.

But the problem seems to be that the plugin script is being placed *before* the jquery script. And the plug-in needs jquery to work. Even though I'm writing the modernizr script tag after the jquery script tag in the markup, the fallback "nope" script is being injected into the page before the jquery script. Huh?

I'm still adjusting to the work of async. Can someone explain how to wrangle this? (I always need to call jquery anyways for other elements on the page, so I can't really make loading jquery conditional on any modernizr test.)

**UPDATE**

Okay, so now I'm (trying to) call everything asychronously. The script tags in the head are declared like this:

```
<script src="js/modernizr-columntest.js"></script>
<script src="js/envision-scriptloader.js"></script>
```

The scriptloader file contains this:

```
Modernizr.load([
    'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js',
    {
        test: Modernizr.csscolumns,
        nope: 'jquery.masonry.min-pluscall.js'
    },
    {
        load: ["js/jquery-smoothscroll.js","js/jquery.colorbox-min.js"],
        complete: function() {
            $.colorbox.settings.fixed = true;
                   // MISCELLANEOUS SETTINGS ETC
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.thumbnail').colorbox({
                    innerWidth: 800,
                });
            });
        }
    }
]);
```

But the baffling thing is that the masonry plugin simply will not fire. In IE 9 Dev Tools, the scripts in the html inspector still appear in reverse order with respect to jquery. Even more strangely, the masonry script appears twice in the generated code, once before jquery and once after. (!) It looks like this in the head:

```
<script src="js/jquery.masonry.min-pluscall.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-smoothscroll.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.masonry.min-pluscall.js"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr-columntest.js"></script>
<script src="js/envision-scriptloader2.js"></script>
```

help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you've hit on this issue. The problem is that jQuery is being loaded synchronously while your plugin is being loaded asynchronously, in IE, it just happens that the plugin loads first, but really, this could happen at any point in any browser. The solution is to load jQuery asynchronously as well, and then load your plugin in the `complete` branch:

```
Modernizr.load({
    load: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js',
    complete: function(){
        Modernizr.load({
            test: Modernizr.csscolumns,
            nope: 'js/jquery.masonry.js'
        });
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

Actually, technically, all you need to do is put them in sequence. This will work as well:

```
Modernizr.load([
    'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js',
    {
        test: Modernizr.csscolumns,
        nope: 'js/jquery.masonry.js'
    }
 ]);
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. I guess it's all or nothing with async, and I have to roll everything into `modernizr.load` if I'm going to use it at all. One corollary question: What do I do about page-specific inline code, page-specific global variables etc? Is there a "best practice" ?

Comment: It's hard to deal with async JS in real world scenarios, honestly. What *I* do is never use it on the page itself, but only within a JS file that *was* loaded sychronously. I have a script tag for jQuery, one for general purpose plugins (combined and minified) and one for application-wide JS -- all synchronous. In the application-wide JS, then, I can load other libraries conditionally and asynchronously with `Modernizr.load`, and it's not a problem, because the file the code is in was loaded synchronously after jQuery.

Comment: well, but that was exactly my problem, wasn't it? I loaded jquery (synchronously, I thought). Then I loaded modernizr (also from a synchronous call, if I'm not mistaken). And so I thought the asynchronously loaded jquery plug-in would execute after jquery, but it was being injected *before* jquery, and thus not running! I'll accept your answer, I'm just trying to understand...

Comment: As long as you only use Modernizr *inside* a JS file that was loaded synchronously after jQuery, there's really no way for the async to be fired before jQuery is loaded. The fact that you've got the aysnc script loaded twice seems to indicate that it's still being loaded on the page as well as in the external JS. Make sure you clear your cache completely in IE, and even better turn on "Always refresh from server" under the "Cache" menu in IE dev tools.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. I also discovered at the bottom of the yepnope docs that seeing double requests is normal. I think this is just some weirdness in the IE inspector, because things are now executing correctly.